# magento 2 : Give id to "column main" div in product listing page

Tags: magento-2.1

For the product listing page I want to give id to to "column main" class div like shown in following picture.

[image]

So to do so in in my custom theme `catalog_category_view.xml`

I've given code like following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="columns" htmlClass="columns container">
            <container name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main" htmlId="hello" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

But that makes whole div empty without setting up id in it, Can anyone tell what mistake I'm making?? Or please explain me what process I should follow to do so ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are adding a new container that is replacing the old one.

Use "referenceContainer" instead of "container" to modify an existing container.

```
<referenceContainer name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main" htmlId="hello" />
```

Comment: It's works  @WilliamOakley, Thanks very much.

Comment: Why did you add `label="Main Content Container"`, `htmlTag="div"` and `htmlId="hello"` ? It also works fine with the `name` and the `htmlClass` only.

Answer (score 0):

Preferred way is to edit in theme's default.xml file. You may create or edit the default.xml file at path **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

If one wants to add container div under column div, should try this.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
           <referenceContainer name="columns">
                <container name="container" label="" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container" />
            </referenceContainer>        
           <move element="main" destination="container" before="-"/>
        </body>
</page>
```